# Build a rss powered website network

Tags: plugin-recommendation, rss

I'm trying to build a website network on my site that is rss powered. It should be similar to http://network.smashingmagazine.com/ in scope except I want the new content posted automatically.

It should work off a cron job perhaps every hour or so and it needs to fit the current template on my site at  http://www.theliverpoolview.com/

Is there any free or open source plugin that does an easy job of this?

Answer (score 1):

FeedWordPress sounds like what you're looking for: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/feedwordpress/